Can I securely allow someone to make payment into my CC account?
Rather than accepting money transfer via something like Venmo, I would prefer that someone simply makes payments into my credit (card) account. Can this be securely set up so that they send a payment to my account without them knowing my CC details? Like is it possible to set up some unique locator within my CC account that can only be paid into (meaning impossible to steal from me)?

What's the benefit of them paying into your CC? What problem are you trying to avoid with Venmo?

It's your third question on the exact same topic, and you still refuse to mention jurisdiction. Laws do differ between places.

I can definitely deposit cash directly into a Credit Card to "deposit" into it in Hong Kong, but I do need to know the card number.

How do you pay off the credit card yourself normally? My polish credit cards have IBANs that I deposit money into to either prepay or pay off their balance. If your card also gets paid off via a bank transfer you could give the second-party those transfer details.


Like is it possible to set up some unique locator within my CC account that can only be paid into (meaning impossible to steal from me)?

Your credit card number is that locator, so no. Virtual credit card numbers are for transactions only and will likely not accept payments.
But the bigger issue is that this opens up a whole plethora of money laundering and tax evasion schemes, and as such even where attempted (like by mailing 3-rd party checks) the credit card companies may want to prevent this. For example, a credit card company may require identification, or prevent third party checks entirely, or (in the US) report such payments to FinCEN. Multiple suspicious transactions will lead to your account closure.
In some countries (e.g.: the US) 3rd party payments may be possible due to its remarkably outdated banking system. You can have anonymous payments with cashier checks or money order, or just bring a wad of cash into a branch. But you still need to identify an account to pay for (= credit card number), and as mentioned before - there are ways for the banking system to deal with such a risk and you may lose your credit card account altogether.

tl;dr: No, most likely not - your credit card account simply cannot accept payments at all (with some exceptions).

Unfortunately, most banks do not offer a way for someone else to transfer money into your credit card account.
The account behind a credit card is not intended as a regular, "full-service" bank account - it is only for processing your credit card payments. The only incoming payments will be refunds resulting from your payments (and possibly transfers by yourself to "prefill" your account so you can spend more than your usual monthly limit).
So no - you generally cannot have someone send money to your credit card account.
That said, some banks to allow incoming transfers.
Two examples:

Revolut supports transfers to cards - though you apparently need the card number for this.
American Express cards in Germany apparently have a linked account with a regular IBAN, which can accept money transfers. I could not find information on whether this also works in countries other than Germany.

So just ask your bank which issued your credit card.

If you want to accept payment, it may be easier to use one of the established money transfer methods (and have an associated account), such as (but not limited to):

PayPal
Venmo
Zelle
bank transfer (ACH, SEPA or similar) into your regular bank account


To answer your question before- Square is a potential option? Also- good answer too.

@sleske your credit card account simply cannot accept payments at all - this appears to be wrong, as Revolut supports sending money to cards. You need to provide the card number and the recipent address. https://help.revolut.com/en-PL/help/transfers/outbound-transfers/card-transfers/which-cards-can-i-send-money-to/

Also you can withdraw money from Trading212 into a credit or debit card - though unlike Revolut they only allow transfers to cards you own

@karolba: Thanks - I stand corrected. I edited my answer with that information.

The best solution I know of is to use a funds transfer service like PayPal, and then have PayPal transfer the money to your bank account, followed by transferring money from the bank account to the credit card. I don't think any of these services let you transfer funds directly back to credit cards, but it might be possible for them to do so, using the same mechanism stores use to issue refunds back to cards.
That does require that the service have your bank account or credit card on file. But that isn't exposed to the other party in the transaction.
So: Might be possible. But you'll have to ask around to find out if any of the payment services actually do it. If you do find a way to do it, you could come back and answer your own question to share the results of your research.
This just isn't something many people really want to do, so there's not going to be a large experience base to advise you.

Once upon a time it was possible to pay your credit card bill with a cheque. I believe it still is, and if so anyone can do it.
In the days of paper credit card bills you paid your bill by filling in the deposit form at the bottom of the bill and mailing it to the credit card company. Enquire if this is still possible. If it is then it doesn't matter who writes the cheque. Get the person to write a cheque in the same way you would and mail it to the credit card company.
The cheque can be for any amount.

This requires providing the credit card number to the person, which could leave open the chance for them to retain the number and use it for online purchases in some circumstances.

And the request was specifically without the payer knowing the card number.

I am writing this answer because I have been in the same situation as you're in- so I know a bit about what to do.
Unfortunately, as I found out, this isn't actually possible- but I have a very good solution that should fit your needs, and this is what I did:
Use Virtual Credit Card Numbers.
VCCNs are unique, and one-time-use credit card numbers that are linked to your real credit card account. When you request a VCCN, your CC provider produces a new unique and randomly generated number that is valid for a specified period of time. I was given the option of having it valid for 1-30 days, when I applied.
The process is automated and I usually used to receive an SMS or email containing my VVCN.
They aren't perfect, but this is why VCCNs are more secure:

They can only be used once, and then expire.
They are anonymous, so they don't give away your real CC number.
You can choose whether they can only be transferred to, but don't have to go the other way.

But, like anything, there are also limitations:

Not all card providers offer them- this one is a big one!
Some providers have limitations on the types of transactions.
Some providers, even if it is a small one, charge a fee.

Check out this link, which covers pretty much everything I've said, that you need to know to make an informed decision.
And if you are interested in this suggestion, then contact your local bank to discuss details and obtain more bank-specific info!

Sorry, but how does this answer the question? OP asked about receiving payment - how does a VCCN help with that?

Yes, this answers the "without them knowing my CC details", but not the "payment into my CC account" part - which seems to be the crucial thing. A VCCN allows you to pay someone without disclosing your regular CC information, but it does not allow receiving payment, does it?

Interesting. I have never heard of a CC (virtual or otherwise) allowing incoming transfers, i.e. receiving money. The Forbes article you link to does not mention it either. Do you have some link to a bank offering this? I think that would be what OP is looking for.

I never really understood the obsession with VCCNs... Seems like a waste of everyone's time and money. Most banks don't offer it because it's just not a useful thing.

VCCN is basically a "one time pad" approach to security -- it means that even if the vendor retains the credit card number they can't make another charge against it. The alternative of being able to turn a card on and off in realtime via a phone app is about the same level of hassle as a VCCN; I'm not sure of the relative security. Personally I just try to be careful about who gets the number to begin with, and resign myself to having to replace the card every few years when someone tries to abuse it.

(Though, on that last topic: Watch out for scammers claiming "false charges have been made on your card, give us your account information so we can stop them". Remember that caller ID can be faked, DO NOT panic, and insist on calling back to the number on your card rather than continuing with their call. I'm careful, and they almost caught me once with this act.)
